What is the numbering convention followed in the reverse strand of a DNA sequence?
The start and end location in forward strand is from 5' to 3' end. Can anyone confirm if the start and end location for genes on the opposite strand, as mentioned in the GTF gene annotation files, the start position is interpreted from the 3'->5' end  or 5'->3' end as illustrated below ?


Summary
There is a single numbering scheme for the base-pairs in the DNA sequences of  genomes. Numbering is from left to right in an agreed, but fundamentally arbitrary, standard orientation for a reference genome (or its chromosomes). Annotated genes assigned to a position within a genome or chromosome may differ in the direction of their transcription, but this is not indicated by any change in numbering, but by some other means. In the GFF/GTF file format a ‘+’/‘–’ system is used to indicate the ‘left-to-right’ (aka ‘forward’) or ‘right-to-left’ (aka ‘reverse’) directions of transcription, respectively.
Clarification of the question
The question refers to the 5′→3′ ends of a genome, whereas 5′→3′ is a direction. The term 5′- and 3′-ends can only be applied to a single strand of a nucleic acid, not to a double-stranded genome.  Furthermore a gene is not located on one or other strand of a genome. Because of these ambiguities, and my difficulty in following the diagram, I shall rephrase the question as:
“Does the numbering scheme for gene annotations within a chromosome differ depending on the orientation of the gene?”
This allows for a broader and more general answer, not restricted to the GTF format with which the poster is specifically concerned. However, I have tried to be precise and unequivocal in my terminology, and welcome comments from anyone who wishes to query or improve it.
Numbering and terminology for double-stranded linear genomes

Double-stranded linear genomes are numbered from one of their physical ends. For any genome there is an agreed reference orientation, although the choice of this orientation can be regarded as arbitrary in absolute terms. In the case of human chromosomes, numbering starts from end of the short arm of each chromosome.
The genome in the reference orientation is visualized horizontally, starting on the ‘left’ and ending on the ‘right’. If both DNA strands are represented (by lines or by letters) then the strand running 5′→3′ is generally visualized above that running 3′→5′ (as in the diagrams in the question).
Data files (and authors) use different terminology to refer to the two strands (see below), but I prefer — and shall generally use — the descriptive terms ‘forward’ and ‘reverse’ for the strands running ‘left-to-right’ (5′→3′) and ‘right-to-left’ (3′→5′), respectively, as they are independent of any functional annotations that may be imposed on parts of the genome.
Although this numbering would also apply to the strand that has its 5′ end on the ‘left’ if it were a single strand, in my opinion it is better to think of the numbering in terms of numbering of base pairs. Thus, genes with different orientations (to be defined below) are generally shown adjacent to a representation of the numbered nucleotide sequence, rather than associated with a particular strand.
Nevertheless, the nucleotide sequence of only one of the strands of a genome — the ‘forward’ strand — is maintained in databases such as GenBank.
Numbering starts at ‘1’ for the first base-pair. (Computer scientists writing software to manipulate sequences tend to dislike this as they generally number strings from’0’.)

These points are illustrated below in a screen-shot of the extreme left of human chromosome 5 in the NCBI genome browser.

Gene orientation
The phrase in the question, “genes on the opposite strand”, though ill-chosen in my opinion, is an obvious reference to the fact that we consider that the genes assigned to parts of the genome are considered to have orientation or directionality, and that there are two possibilities in this respect: running ‘left-to-right’ (in relation to the standard visualization of the parent genome) or in the opposite direction (right-to-left).
What is the basis for assigning such an orientation? Often (as in the phraseology of the question), this is related to interpretation of the potential for expression and the relationship of the conventional direction in which the products of expression are written to that of the two DNA strands of the genome. This runs into problems of different types of product (mRNA followed by protein, or stable RNAs) and that the direction in which these are conventionally written is essentially arbitrary. In fact, I think it far better to consider this in relation to the direction of transcription, a process that involves physical movement of an RNA polymerase in a specific direction from a promoter sequence. This can be illustrated in the figure below, modified from Alberts et al.. which embodies the essential point that transcription proceeds in a particular direction from a (asymmetric) promoter sequence (p).

It is worth emphasizing that only one of the two strands of DNA of a gene is transcribed into RNA by DNA-dependent RNA polymerase. This, is what I prefer to refer to as the ‘anti-sense’ strand of the gene (the term cannot be applied to the genome), and results in a transcript which is an RNA copy of the ‘sense’ strand,  i.e. the DNA strand that ‘reads’ from 5′→3′ in the same way as the mature RNA (except for the substitution of U for T). (If the RNA transcript is a mRNA, the amino acid sequence of the protein product also has the same directionality as the ‘sense’ strand.) This is illustrated in the diagram below.

Gene orientation and NCBI file format
The NCBI website distinguishes between genes in different orientations by appending ‘complement’ before the number co-ordinates if the direction of a gene is in the reverse direction with respect to the genome:

The designation, ‘complement’. is not frequently employed elsewhere, but refers to the fact that the direction is that of the complement of the forward strand of the genome, the sequence of which is that deposited in NCBI/GenBank. See also the sample GenBank record at NCBI.
Gene orientation and GTF file format
The GTF format is derived from the GFF format, which is a tab-separated machine-readable file format in which there is a column (field 7) to indicate the orientation. This may take values of ‘+’ for genes oriented in the same direction as the forward strand or ‘–’ for the those with the same orientation as the reverse strand.
NC_004354.4 RefSeq  gene    124370  126714  .   -   .   ID=gene-Dmel_CG17636;Dbxref=FLYBASE:FBgn0025837,GeneID:5740847;Name=CG17636;cyt_map=1A1-1A1;gbkey=Gene;gen_map=1-0 cM;gene=CG17636;gene_biotype=protein_coding;gene_synonym=Dmel\CG17636,EG:23E12.1;locus_tag=Dmel_CG17636
NC_004354.4 RefSeq  mRNA    124370  126714  .   -   .   ID=rna-NM_001103384.3;Parent=gene-Dmel_CG17636;Dbxref=FLYBASE:FBtr0112921,GeneID:5740847,GenBank:NM_001103384.3,FLYBASE:FBgn0025837;Name=NM_001103384.3;Note=CG17636-RA%3B Dmel\CG17636-RA;gbkey=mRNA;gene=CG17636;locus_tag=Dmel_CG17636;orig_protein_id=gnl|FlyBase|CG17636-PA|gb|ABW09315;orig_transcript_id=gnl|FlyBase|CG17636-RA;product=uncharacterized protein%2C transcript variant A;transcript_id=NM_001103384.3
NC_004354.4 RefSeq  exon    126626  126714  .   -   .   ID=exon-NM_001103384.3-1;Parent=rna-NM_001103384.3;Dbxref=FLYBASE:FBtr0112921,GeneID:5740847,GenBank:NM_001103384.3,FLYBASE:FBgn0025837;Note=CG17636-RA%3B Dmel\CG17636-RA;gbkey=mRNA;gene=CG17636;locus_tag=Dmel_CG17636;orig_protein_id=gnl|FlyBase|CG17636-PA|gb|ABW09315;orig_transcript_id=gnl|FlyBase|CG17636-RA;product=uncharacterized protein%2C transcript variant A;transcript_id=NM_001103384.3

(Values of ‘.’ and ‘?’ are also possible.)
Although convenient for data files, I discourage the use of ‘+’ and ‘-’ as descriptive terms because of their use in relation to the strands of single-stranded RNA viruses.
Footnote: Terminology for the DNA strands of genes
In an answer to a previous question on SE Biology I discussed the terminology of the two strands of the DNA of an individual gene, which I think should be considered in isolation from (and in ignorance of) the reference directionality of the genome on or in which it resides. The terminologies for gene and genome are clearly distinct.

GTF format is the same as GFF v2. The start and end fields are relative to the first position in the reference sequence which is assigned coordinate 1. The reference sequence, by definition, is the +/forward strand, so all coordinates are relative to the forward strand. The start coordinate will always be less than the end coordinate. If a feature is stranded (like a gene) the strand for the feature will be indicated by a '+' or '-' in the 7th field. Scenario A in your diagram is correct.
